# MSSQL leaking connections

Tags: sql-server, go

I have strange issue with golang sql and probably denisenkom/go-mssqldb.

My code part:

```
func Auth(username string, password string, remote_ip string, user_agent string) (string, User, error) {
var token string
var user = User{}

query := `exec dbo.sp_get_user ?,?`

rows, err := DB.Query(query, username, password)
if err != nil {
    return token, user, err
}
defer rows.Close()

rows.Next()
if err = rows.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Username, &user.Description); err != nil {
    log.Printf("SQL SCAN: Failed scan User in Auth. %v \n", err)
    return token, user, err
}

hashFunc := md5.New()
hashFunc.Write([]byte(username + time.Now().String()))

token = hex.EncodeToString(hashFunc.Sum(nil))

query = `exec dbo.sp_set_session ?,?,?,?`

_, err = DB.Exec(query, user.Id, token, remote_ip, user_agent)
if err != nil {
    return token, user, err
}

return token, user, nil
}
```

Problem: `defer rows.Close()` - not working properly

After this with `DB.Connection.Stats().OpenConnections` I always have 2 connection opened (also after repeat User login is still 2 connection for whole app lifecycle)

But if I rewrite func as:

```
...
    query := `exec dbo.sp_get_user ?,?`

    rows, err := DB.Query(query, username, password)
    if err != nil {
        return token, user, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    rows.Next()
    if err = rows.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Username, &user.Description); err != nil {
        log.Printf("SQL SCAN: Failed scan User in Auth. %v \n", err)
        return token, user, err
    }

    rows.Close()
...
```

Then rows underline stmt is closed and next `DB.Connection.Stats().OpenConnections` always will be 1 connection open.

`DB` in my app is simply return underlying connection from `sql.Open`

Problem is only in this part where two query executions with `Query` and `Exec` in one functions.

Maybe `Query` and `Exec` defines different connections, but i don't find this in driver source or database/sql source.

Thank you! (sorry for english if it's so bad)

PS:

`exec dbo.sp_get_user ?,?` - is simple select from user table, not more.

`exec dbo.sp_set_session ?,?,?,?` - is simple insert to user table, not more

In MSSQL - `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` shows me query = `'cast(@@identity as bigint)'` which executes in denisenkom/go-mssqldb mssql.go on line 593

Comment: If you know when you can call `rows.Close()` then just do it yourself. You can call `Close` any number of times, so the `defer` is for "just in case".

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, thx you, but I want to know why this hapens. Because `defer` statement puts execution just after function where it's call and theriotically must work same as close in second variant.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `defer`s are not run in the event of a `panic`.

Comment: Er wait, yes, as you stated, `Query` and `Exec` here WILL use two different connections. The one from `Query` is not released to the pool until `Close` is called, so `Exec` allocates another. Which goes back to my original comment. If you know you are done with it, `Close` it ASAP.

Comment: Also check rows.Err, see [Retrieving Result Sets](http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html).

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I separate `rows.Close()` in different func `rows_close (rows *sql.Rows) {}`. Then `defer rows_close(rows)`. Inside this func I check errors - and there is now error in `Close` and not `Panic`. I understand that will be 2 connection inside function, but after func on whole app lifecycle it's still 2 connections that reused. If I remove this Auth func - 1 connection for app lifecycle.

Comment: @Mark rows.Err() return nil